# R substitute values csv

Tags: r, csv, import, tidyverse

given the following minimal reproducible example (reprex)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

mydf<-read_csv("datetime,x,y,z\n
          12/03/2020 01,,< 2.5,1.5\n
          12/03/2020 02,1.1,4.5,<0.5\n
          12/03/2020 03,<1,6.5,")

mydf
```

I need to trasform imported data to the appropriate type (datetime and double) and substitute values marked as "less than" (<) with corresponding halved numerical values;

this is my expected final result

```
mydf_final<-read_csv("datetime,x,y,z\n
          2020-03-12 01:00,,1.25,1.5\n
          2020-03-12 02:00,1.1,4.5,0.25\n
          2020-03-12 03:00,0.5,6.5,")

mydf_final
```

up to now I worked out this solution, which seems to me a bit rough but I can't imagine something more elegant and efficient

```
#define a function to have values if less than...
halve_value<-function(x) ifelse(str_starts(x, "<"), as.numeric(gsub("<", "", x))/2, as.numeric(x))

mydf%>%
  mutate(datetime=parse_date_time(datetime, '%d/%m/%Y %H'))%>%
  mutate_at(2:4, halve_value)
```

any suggestion to improve my approach by considering that the dataset I should deal with is big enough?

is there any way to set the appropriate datatype and corresponding halved values on beforehand, just in the very same time as they are imported via the function read_csv?

is that anyhow more convenient?

thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(readr)
mydf<-read_csv("datetime,x,y,z\n
          12/03/2020 01,,< 2.5,1.5\n
          12/03/2020 02,1.1,4.5,<0.5\n
          12/03/2020 03,<1,6.5,")

library(dplyr)

mydf %>% mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H"),
                across(c(x, y, z), ~ ifelse(grepl('<', .), as.numeric(gsub('<\\s*', '', .)) * 0.5, as.numeric(.)) ))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   datetime                x     y     z
#>   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2020-03-12 01:00:00  NA    1.25  1.5 
#> 2 2020-03-12 02:00:00   1.1  4.5   0.25
#> 3 2020-03-12 03:00:00   0.5  6.5  NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>